# How to calculate refractive index $n$ from absorbance, transmittance or reflectance spectra?

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, reflection, refraction

I have absorbance (Abs), reflectance (R%) and transmittance (T%) data of $\rm TiO_2$ deposited tin film on FTO glass substrate. The data was collected using UV-Vis spectrophotometer.

How to calculate refractive index $n$ from this?

from the refractive index I will estimate the film thickness, then I will estimate the band gap of the thin film.

I tried with n = (1 + R^1/2) / (1 - R^1/2) where R is reflectance,
and with Sweaneopeol method , but **it shows large deviation from reported value**.

Kindly suggest how to proceed.

Comment: @Mike hello, no it did not , but I already use the Dektak to measure our powder thin film.. Thank you!

Comment: I didn't actually write that; it's an automatically generated comment from my vote to close this question as a duplicate of your other two questions that were almost identical.  In the future, please don't ask the same thing multiple times.  Much like asking "homework-like" questions, that is considered bad form on this site.